# UIVIew: Is there a way to have multiple tags to retrieve the superview?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios7

I'm coding for iOS7.
I have a grouped UITableView, with 3 different sections, each one of them has multiple rows.
In every row there is an UITextField added as accessoryView:

```
UITextField *myTextField = [UITextField alloc] init];
cell.accessoryView = myTextField;
```

I need to retrieve the right cell/textField in other places of my code, for example this code was working up to iOS6:

```
-(void) textFieldValueDidChange: (UITextField*) sender
{
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell: (UITableViewCell*) sender.superview];

 switch (indexPath.section){

  case(SECTION_1):{

      switch(indexPath.row){

        case(ROW_1):{
          //DO SOMETHING
        }

      }

  }

 }
}
```

This kind of code breaks in iOS7.

On another thread someone suggested to me to never retrieve my subviews like this but to assign the indexPath.row value to the tag property of the sender when the cell is created and then retrieve the right cell from it. This works perfectly when the table is a normal one and I am dealing just with the row number but here I have to keep track ***both of the row and the sections*** and there is only one tag property.

What would be my best option to deal with it? I thought about adding 1000, 2000, 3000 etc.. to keep track of the section, example: 2003 would mean indexPath.section = 2 and indexPath.row = 3 but this doesn't apper an elegant solution to me. Any idea?

Thanks

Nicola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating a category on UIView with a property that will hold the indexPath?

.h:

```
@interface UIView (IndexPathTag)

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *indexPathTag;
```

.m

```
@implementation UIView(IndexPathTag)
```

Then, in your code, if you import UIView+IndexPath, you can do:

```
#import "UIView+IndexPathTag.h"

myView = [[UIView alloc] init];

 myView.indexPathTag = indexPath;
```